# Fastest way to find the nearest element in the array of real numbers

Tags: python, search, tree, binary-search-tree, kdtree

For a given array of real numbers for each element, find the number of elements which is less than current element by no more than `0.5` and write to new array.

For example:

Original array:

```
[0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
```

Result array:

```
[0,   0,   1,   2,    3,   0,   1]
```

What are the algorithms and approaches to solve this problem?

It is important that the neighborhood of the points is chosen only in the negative direction, which makes it impossible to use the `Kdtree` or `Balltree` algorithms.

All of my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569023/nearest-neighbors-in-a-given-range) with my try of code it.

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Comment: All of my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569023/nearest-neighbors-in-a-given-range) with my try of code it.

Comment: Are the numbers always sorted?

Comment: @max9111 No, they are not sorted

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your specific task.

```
def find_nearest_element(original_array):
    result_array = []
    for e in original_array:
        result_array.append(len(original_array[(e-0.5 < original_array) & (e > original_array)]))
    return result_array

original_array = np.array([0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7])
print(find_nearest_element(original_array))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

EDIT: Using a mask is apparantly faster than the version using numba for smaller arrays(ca. len 10000). For bigger arrays the version of using Numba is faster. So it depends on what size of arrays you want to progress.

Some runtime comparison(in seconds):

```
For smaller arrays(size=250):
Using Numba 0.2569999694824219
Using mask 0.0350041389465332
For bigger arrays(size=40000):
Using Numba 1.4619991779327393
Using mask 4.280000686645508
```

The break even point on my device is around size 10000(both take ca. 0.33 seconds).

Comment: Really interesting, thanks for the time comparisons! (although, maybe this should not be formatted as a code block?)

Comment: I think so, too. But the distance between the lines gets really big if i dont put it in the code block :/ At least it is an output of a script^^

Comment: Do you mean "both take ca. 0.33 seconds"?

Answer (score 0):

Although the method below uses simple logic and is easy to write, it is slow. We can speed it up by using a decorated [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) function. This will speed up simple looping tasks to near assembly language speeds.

Install Numba with `pip install numba`.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

# Create a numpy array of length 10000 with float values between 0 and 10
random_values = np.random.uniform(0.0,10.0,size=(100*100,))

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def find_nearest(input):
  result = []
  for e in input:
    counter = 0
    for j in input:
      if j >= (e-0.5) and j < e:
        counter += 1
    result.append(counter)
  return result

result = find_nearest(random_values)
```

Note that the intended result is returned for the test case:

```
test = [0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
result = find_nearest(test)
print result
```

Returns:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This is a very slow decision that has difficulty O(n^2).

Comment: There was no mention of speed optimization in the post.... but yes this is likely not the speediest.

Comment: Also not what he wants, as he is only interested in comparing the current number to the left side of the array.

Comment: Really? I don't read the question that way.... "neighborhood of the points is chosen only in the negative direction" means that the searching neighborhood distance is 0.5, but is restricted to only searching for values within x - 0.5 (where x is the target value). Instead of x +/- 0.5.

Comment: @Иван I have modified my answer for better speed optimization.

Comment: You are right. I found a solution using a mask, this is a bit faster for small arrays(e.g. your example with 10000 lenght. However, when increasing the number your code is faster. Depends on his use case i guess.

Comment: @PJW  Okay, all of my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569023/nearest-neighbors-in-a-given-range) with my try of code it.

Comment: But the code is from somebody else. Do our answers solve your problem or did we not interpret is correctly?

Comment: @f.wue Here is a part of  the problem. Your answers solve the problem correctly, but work slowly. I would like to know which solutions are the fastest for such a task.

Comment: @Иван How big of an array are you searching?

Comment: @PJW 1 000 000 elements.

Comment: For that length, the numba method would take ~36 seconds to execute, according to @f.wue 's timing metrics.

Comment: Would take even longer. For arrays that big our solutions are not fast...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is quite easy to solve for ordered arrays. You have to just search backwards and count all numbers which are bigger than the actual number-radius. If that condition isn't met anymore you can break out of the inner loop (which saves a lot of time).

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def get_counts_2(Points_sorted,ind,r):
  counts=np.zeros(Points_sorted.shape[0],dtype=np.int64)
  for i in nb.prange(0,Points_sorted.shape[0]):
    count=0
    for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
      if (Points_sorted[i]-r<Points_sorted[j]):
        count+=1
      else:
        break
    counts[ind[i]]=count
  return counts
```

**Timings**

```
r=0.001
Points=np.random.rand(1_000_000)

t1=time.time()
ind=np.argsort(Points)
Points_sorted=Points[ind]
counts=get_counts_2(Points_sorted,ind,r)
print(time.time()-t1)
#0.29s
```